# Reference Request for The Study of Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups

So I finished Lang's Algebra and after reading this partial [Structure Theorem for abelian torsion groups that are not finitely generated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22646/) , I've gotten interested in abelian groups, in particular infinite abelian groups and structure theorems. Can anyone recommend a book that highlights these topics?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though I haven't read it myself, [Kaplansky's book *Infinite Abelian Groups*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047208500X) seems like it is just right for you. Here are the contents:

[image]

Comment: Hm, I just picked it up in the stacks. Seems short and sweet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A more in-depth, and therefore substantially longer, book is Fuch's *Abelian Groups*. I won't paste in the contents, as they run to three pages!

I notice that the review of Kaplansky's book refers the reader to Fuch's *Infinite Abelian Groups, Vol I and II*. These are more modern than *Abelian Groups*, published in 1973 I believe as opposed to 1960. However, *Abelian Groups* can be picked up for [9.00 Dollars](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0007IU4RE) as opposed to [34.31 Dollars](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122696018) (Vol. I) + [186.06 Dollars](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0122696026) (Vol. II) = a lot more than 9 Dollars.

Comment: Ironically, I found Fuch right next to Kapalnsky in the stacks, and picked it up after remembering the name in the last section. Thanks for affirming that I should read it!