# What are $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb Q, \oplus_k \mathbb Z/p^k)$ and $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb Z/p^\infty, \oplus_k \mathbb Z /p^k)$?

Tags: modules, homological-algebra, abelian-groups

**Motivation:** Let $p$ be a prime. I learned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22665/45082) that by a theorem of Kulikov, every abelian $p$-group $A$ is an extension of a divisible group by a direct sum of cyclic groups. That is, we have a short exact sequence

$$ 0 \to B \to A \to (\mathbb Z / p^\infty)^{(J)} \to 0$$

where $B = \oplus (\mathbb Z/p^k)^{(I_k)}$ is a sum of cyclic groups (I denote by $X^{(I)}$ an $I$-fold direct sum of copies of $X$). This motivates studying the groups

$$\operatorname{Ext}((\mathbb Z / p^\infty)^{(J)}, B) = \operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb Z / p^\infty, B)^J$$

for such $B$ as an approach to classifying $p$-groups. Moreover, the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb Z_{(p)} \to \mathbb Q \to \mathbb Z / p^\infty \to 0$ yields a short exact sequence

$$0 \to B \to \operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb Z/p^\infty, B) \to \operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb Q, B) \to 0$$

So it seems natural to start by studying $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb Q, B)$.

If $B$ is of bounded exponent, then both $\operatorname{Ext}$ groups vanish. So the simplest interesting case should be $B = \oplus_{k \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z / p^k$. Thus I ask

**Question 1:** What is $\operatorname{Ext}(\mathbb Q, \oplus_{k \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z / p^k)$?

I believe this is a divisible group, so it is of the form $\mathbb Q^{(I)} \oplus (\mathbb Z / p^\infty)^{(J)}$, so the question is to identify the cardinalities $I$ and $J$.

Everything can also be done $p$-adically, and I think I can see that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb Z}(\mathbb Q, B)$ is actually *isomorphic* to $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb Z_p}(\mathbb Q_p, B)$. So a more refined question is

**Question 2:** What is $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb Z_p}(\mathbb Q_p, \oplus_{k \in \mathbb N} \mathbb Z / p^k)$ (as a $\mathbb Z_p$-module)?

Similarly to before, it should be of the form $\mathbb Q_p^{(I')} \oplus \mathbb (\mathbb Z/p^\infty)^{(J)}$ so the question is to identify the cardinalities $I'$ and $J$.

Answer (score 4):

Not a complete answer. I'm going to write $\text{Rlim}$ for $\lim^1$ because I can't figure out how to get $\lim^1$ to look nice. Writing $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty} \cong \text{colim}_n \, \mathbb{Z}/p^n$ gives a short exact sequence

$$0 \to \text{Rlim}_n \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^n, B) \to \text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}, B) \to \lim_n \text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^n, B) \to 0.$$

The rightmost term is just $\lim_n B/p^n B$, the $p$-completion of $B$. So I think this means $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}, B)$ is what people call [derived $p$-completion](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.07633), and I guess the $\text{Rlim}$ term can be nontrivial in general. $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Q}, B)$ is then the quotient of whatever this is by the image of $B$.

By functoriality, if $B$ is a $p$-group then $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Q}, B)$ inherits both an action of $\mathbb{Q}$ and an action of $\mathbb{Z}_p$, so overall has an action of $\mathbb{Q} \otimes \mathbb{Z}_p \cong \mathbb{Q}_p$, and hence must be a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of some dimension (and this determines its $\mathbb{Z}_p$-module structure also). As you say we also have $\text{Ext}(\mathbb{Q}, B) \cong \text{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}_p}(\mathbb{Q}_p, B)$ via the short exact sequence

$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Q}_p \to \mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p \to 0$$

which makes the $\mathbb{Q}_p$-action a little easier to see.

When $B = \oplus_k \mathbb{Z}/p^k$ I believe (but haven't checked carefully) that the $p$-completion ought to be $\prod_k \mathbb{Z}/p^k$. Unfortunately the $\text{Rlim}$ term doesn't satisfy the Mittag-Leffler condition.

**Edit:** Okay, here's an alternative to try. We can instead start with the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac 1 p \right] \to \mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty} \to 0$, which produces another very similar short exact sequence

$$0 \to B \to \text{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}, B) \to \text{Ext}\left( \mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac 1 p \right], B \right) \to 0.$$

Writing $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac 1 p \right] \cong \text{colim} \left( \cdots \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z} \cdots \right)$ gives a short exact sequence

$$0 \to \text{Rlim } B \to \text{Ext}\left( \mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac 1 p \right], B \right) \to \lim B \to 0.$$

Now both the $\text{Rlim}$ term and the $\lim$ term are simpler. $\lim B$ is the limit of the sequence $\cdots B \xrightarrow{p} B \xrightarrow{p} B \cdots$ which is $\text{Hom} \left( \mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac 1 p \right], B \right) = 0$. This means we have an isomorphism $\text{Rlim } B \cong \text{Ext} \left( \mathbb{Z} \left[ \frac 1 p \right], B \right)$, where $\text{Rlim } B$ is the cokernel of the map

$$\prod_n B \xrightarrow{\partial} \prod_n B$$

where $\partial(\{ b_n \}) = \{ b_n - p b_{n+1} \}$ (and $\lim B$ is the kernel). This should be easier to understand although I admit I am not excited about the double indices necessary to understand this for $B = \oplus_k \mathbb{Z}/p^k$. Maybe this will help though.

Comment: Hang on -- $Ext$ should send filtered colimits in the first variable to _derived_ cofiltered limits -- so shouldn't there be a $\varprojlim^1$ term here too?

Comment: @tcamps: okay, fixed. Now I suppose I should learn how to compute $\lim^1$...

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how the different decompositions we're using relate. Incidentally, I think the completion of $\oplus_k \mathbb Z/p^k$ is the subgroup of $\{(x_1,x_2,\dots) \in \prod_k \mathbb Z/p^k \mid \lim_{i\to \infty} v_p(x_i) = \infty\}$ where $v_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation. These $\varprojlim^1$ calculation do seem to be difficult... maybe there's a bit of additional structure -- one might expect that the $\mathbb Q_p$-vector spaces in question are complete in the $p$-adic norm, so maybe the thing to do is to look for a linearly independent dense subset rather than a basis...

Comment: Here $\mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb Z/p^\infty,B)$ is the derived $p$-completion of $B$, but that's because $\hom(\mathbb Z/p^\infty,B)=0$ (in general, the derived $p$-completion is equivalent to $\Sigma Hom(\mathbb Z/p^\infty,B)$, where $Hom$ is the internal hom in $D(\mathbb Z)$. So actually from your edit, one is reduced to computing said derived $p$-completion, which is also the homotopy limit of $\mathbb Z/p^n\otimes_\mathbb Z^L B$ - perhaps that's doable

Comment: In general, $Ext(\mathbb Z/p^\infty,-)$ is still the localization functor $L$ from $Ab$ to the full subcategory of $p$-complete abelian groups, i.e. groups $A$ such that $Hom(\mathbb Z[1/p],A) = Ext(\mathbb Z[1/p], A) = 0$. The existence of such a functor $L$ follows from abstract nonsense -- $p$-complete groups are closed under products, kernels, and $\omega_1$-filtered colimits. If $\hat L$ is the corresponding localization functor in $D(\mathbb Z)$, we have $L A = (\hat L A[0])_0$...

Comment: ... To see this, first observe that it holds for free abelian groups: this follows from the fact that $p$-completeness in $D(\mathbb Z)$ is equivalent to each homology group being $p$-complete, because $D(\mathbb Z)^\heartsuit = Ab$, and from compuing that $\hat L (F[0])$ is concentrated in degree 0 when $F$ is free. Then, because $p$-complete groups are closed under cokernels, $L$ preserves the cokernel of a free resolution of any $A \in Ab$, and the formula for $A$ follows. Thus since we know $\hat L = \Sigma RHom(\mathbb Z/p^\infty[0],-)$, it follows that $L = Ext(\mathbb Z/p^\infty,-)$.

Comment: So I want to call $L = Ext(\mathbb Z / p^\infty,-)$ the "genuine underived $p$-completion functor" or something. It's an extension of the "naive underived $p$-completion functor" $\varprojlim_k (-)/p^k$ by $\varprojlim^1_k (-)[p^k]$, which often vanishes.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Ext}{Ext}$
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$
$\newcommand{\Zp}{{\mathbb{Z}_p}}$
$\newcommand{\Qp}{{\mathbb{Q}_p}}$
$\newcommand{\div}{\mathrm{div}}$
$\newcommand{\tor}{\mathrm{tor}}$
Still not a complete answer, but here's some more progress, I think. Let $B$ be a direct sum of cyclic abelian $p$-groups. All $\Hom$'s, $\Ext$'s, $\otimes$'s, etc. are over $\Zp$.

**Theorem 1:** $\Ext(\Qp, B) \cong \Hom(\Qp, \hat B / B) \cong \Qp \otimes \widehat{\Zp^{(I)}} \oplus \Qp^{(J)}$ where

- $I = \dim_{\mathbb F_p}((\hat B / B)[p])$
- $J = \dim_{\Qp}((\hat B / B)/(\hat B / B)^\tor)$

Here $\hat B = \varprojlim_k B/p^k$ denotes the $p$-completion of $B$, $(-)^\tor$ denotes the torsion subgroup, and $[p]$ denotes the kernel of multiplication by $p$.

---

We can be more concrete about this. Write $B'$ for the corresponding product of cyclic groups, i.e. if $B = \oplus_k (\Zp/p^k)^{(I_k)}$, then $B' = \prod_k (\Zp/p^k)^{I_k}$. Then we have

**Proposition 2:** The natural inclusion $B \to B'$ factors through $\hat B$, and

- $B = \{(x_{k,i}) \in B' \mid x_{k,i} \to 0\}$
- $\hat B = \{(x_{k,i}) \in B' \mid v_p(x_{k,i}) \to \infty\}$
- $(\hat B / B)[p] = \{(x_{k,i}) \in \hat B \mid k - v_p(x_{k,i}) \text{ is bounded by }1\} / B[p]$
- $(\hat B / B)^\tor = \{(x_{k,i}) \in \hat B \mid k - v_p(x_{k,i}) \text{ is bounded}\} / B$

In particular, the maps $B \to \hat B$ and $\hat B \to B'$ are monic. Moreover, $\hat B / B$ is divisible.

Here, $x_{k,i} \to 0$ means that $x_{k,i} = 0$ for all but finitely many $(k,i)$. Similarly, $v_p(x_{k,i}) \to \infty$ means that for each $n \in \mathbb N$, $v_p(x_{k,i}) \geq n$ for all but finitely many $(k,i)$, where $v_p$ is the $p$-adic valuation.

**Proof:** Straightforward.

---

**Lemma 3:** $\Ext(\Qp,\hat B) = 0$.

**Proof:** The short exact sequence $0 \to \hat B \to B' \to B'/\hat B \to 0$ yields an exact sequence $\Hom(\Qp, B' / \hat B) \to \Ext(\Qp,\hat B) \to \Ext(\Qp,B')$. The last term vanishes because $\Ext(\Qp,\Zp/p^k) = 0$ and $\Ext(\Qp,-)$ commutes with products. To see that the first term vanishes, it suffices to show that the divisible part of $B'/\hat B$ is zero, which can be done using the explicit descriptions of Proposition 2.

---

**Lemma 4:**

- If $D$ is a divisible $\Zp$-module, then $D \cong D^\tor \oplus D/D^\tor$. Moreover, $D^\tor \cong (\mathbb Z/p^\infty)^{(I)}$ where $I = \dim_{\mathbb F_p} D[p]$, while $D/D^\tor$ is a $\Qp$-vector space.
- $\Hom(\mathbb Z/p^\infty, (\mathbb Z/p^\infty)^{(I)}) \cong \widehat{\Zp^{(I)}}$ and $\Hom(\Qp, (\mathbb Z/p^\infty)^{(I)}) \cong \Qp \otimes \widehat{\Zp^{(I)}}$

**Proof:** The first bullet is clear. For the second, use the expression $\mathbb Z / p^\infty = \varinjlim_k \mathbb Z/p^k$, which is carried to a $\varprojlim$ by $\Hom$. Then observe that every homomorphism $\Qp \to (\mathbb Z/p^\infty)^{(I)}$ descends to $\mathbb Z / p^\infty \to (\mathbb Z/ p^\infty)^{(I)}$ after multiplication by some power of $p$.

---

**Proof of Theorem 1:** The short exact sequence $0 \to B \to \hat B \to \hat B / B \to 0$ induces an exact sequence $\Hom(\Qp,\hat B) \to \Hom(\Qp,\hat B / B) \to \Ext(\Qp,B) \to \Ext(\Qp,\hat B)$. The last term vanishes by Lemma 3. To see that the first term vanishes, it suffices to observe that the divisible part of $\hat B$ is zero, which is obvious from the description of Proposition 2. So the middle map is an isomorphism. This establishes the first isomorphism of Theorem 1. The second follows from Lemma 4 and the divisibility of $\hat B / B$.

---

**Dimension count:** Recall that we are considering $B = \oplus_k (\mathbb Z / p^k)^{(I_k)}$, where we are assuming the torsion is not bounded, i.e. there are infinitely many $k$ with $I_k \neq 0$.

1. $(\hat B / B)[p]$ is infinite-dimensional, so its $\mathbb F_p$-dimension is the same as its cardinality, which is clearly $I = \max(2^{\aleph_0}, \inf_n \prod_{k \geq n \mid I_k \geq \aleph_0} I_k)$. In particular, $(\hat B / B)[p]$ is at least continuum-dimensional. Therefore, $\Qp \otimes \widehat{\Zp^{(I)}}$ has dimension at least the continuum, and so its dimension is the same as its cardinality, which is the same as the cardinality of $\widehat{\Zp^{(I)}} = \varprojlim_k (\mathbb Z / p^k)^{(I)}$. To choose an element of this set, we first choose an element of $(\mathbb Z / p)^{(I)}$ ($I$ many choices), then we choose an element of $(p\mathbb Z / p^2)^{(I)}$ ($I$ many choices), and so forth, for a total cardinality of $I^{\aleph_0}$. Thus $\dim_{Qp}(\Qp \otimes \widehat{\Zp^{(I)}}) = I^{\aleph_0} \max(2^{\aleph_0}, \inf_n \prod_{k \geq n \mid I_k \geq \aleph_0} I_k^{\aleph_0})$.
2. A similar calculation shows that $J = I$.

Thus $\dim_\Qp(\Ext(\mathbb Z / p^\infty, B)) = I^{\aleph_0} = \max(2^{\aleph_0}, \inf_n \prod_{k \geq n \mid I_k \geq \aleph_0} I_k^{\aleph_0})$.